# Strange and random occuring Assembly not found error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, json

I did a simple ajax services (json based) to get some data from database.
 The problem stated below:

On localhost: while programming/editing the aspx page in visual studio and seeing the result in browser it works fine for say 5-6 times of editing the aspx page, and then just start failing. Until I go to my web service interface class do something (say just put a newline somewhere) and recompile it. The problem get fixed and the cycle goes on...

When I trace the failed requests in fire bug I found 500 internal server error:
 [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_lbgnha4m, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
 *full stack trace below.

I am not sure, but looks like this file 'App_Web_lbgnha4m' is generated temporary because everytime I fix this error by recompiling the code. After some time it again comes back with new name 'App_Web_blahblahblah'

My biggest concern is that when I deploy the solution to my staging server. the service worked fine (say for a day) and then same error, quite surprised what goes wrong without touching a file once deployed). Obviously I can’t deploy the solution every day to fix this....

Any suggestions please help......

Full Stack Trace:

```
[FileNotFoundException]: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_lbgnha4m, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
[ServiceActivationException]: The service '/Website/RESTfulService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_lbgnha4m, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to an ASP.NET Web Application project.